# Do i need to protect a DC adapter from current spikes (produced by buck converter)?

Tags: circuit-protection, smoothing-capacitor

I wonder if i need to protect my ac adapter, which has **over-voltage, over-current and short-circuit protection.** The ac adapter feeds a buck-converter which uses a low-side n-mosfet switch configuration.

I made 2 LTSpice simulations, as seen in the image attached.

In the simulation on the left hand side I added a 10mF capacitor. This way i could smooth the current originating from the power supply. For comparison, i set the capacitance of the capacitor to 0mF.

In the online stores i know, i couldn't find a 10mF non-polarized capacitor for my application. But i don't know if it is need in the first place.

Kind regards
[image: buck converter simulation]

Comment: No. Why would you? Worry about cable inductance and max load dropping to zero or vice versa.

Comment: Consider a 200kHz and 100uF and cap rated for >2Arms ripple current

Comment: @winny could you elaborate what there is to worry about, regarding the 2 aspects you mentioned? I can't imagine either aspect by just thinking about it. @ Tony thanks for the hint

Comment: You need to make sure your input cap can more than absorb the energy stored in the inductance of the cable. For most cases, this isn’t an issue due to short cables and big input caps, but you should always include a check that C(deltaU)^2/2 > LIpk^2/2, where deltaU is the maximum increase in voltage you can tolerate. If your C is zero, this will always be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

C2 helps with efficiency, else you're relying on the output capacitor in the DC adapter to deal with the ripple current, which might exceed its capability.

it depends on lots of stuff, a linear adapter may not hande ripple wall 
at all, but a switcher will likely handle it better, but nay not be able to maintain full rated output.

plus you also have radiated interference from the DC cable, especially if it's a flat pair.

better to spend 10c on an input filter capacitor

Comment: this is understandable and imaginable, but do you know if parts of the dc adapter would get damaged if the ripple current is large? Do you perhaps know how big the output capacitors of DC adapters are? Thanks for the inspiration.